# Index a vector by a matrix of conditions to obtain multiple selections of the target?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, indexing, octave

I have a vector `T` of length `n` and `m` other vectors of the same length with `0` or `1` used as condition to select elements of `T`. The condition vectors are combined into a matrix `I` of size `n x m`.

Is there a one liner to extract a matrix `M` of values from `T`such that the i-th column of `M` are those elements in `T` that are selected by the condition elements of the i-th column in `I`?

Example:

```
T = (1:10)'
I = mod(T,2) == 0
T(I)'
```

yields

```
2    4    6    8   10
```

However

```
I = mod(T,2:4) == 0
T(I)'
```

yields an error in the last statement. I see that the columns might select a different number of elements which results in vectors of different lengths (as in the example). However, even this example doesn't work:

```
I = zeros(10,2)
I(:,1) = mod(T,2)==0
I(:,2) = mod(T,2)==1
```

Is there any way to achieve the solution in a one liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to do something like this is to take advantage of the element-wise multiplication operator `.*` with your matrix `I`.  Take this as an example:

```
% these lines are just setup of your problem
m = 10;
n = 10;
T = [1:m]';
I = randi([0 1], m, n);
% 1 liner to create M
M = repmat(T, 1, n) .* I;
```

What this does is expand `T` to be the same size as `I` using `repmat` and then multiplies all the elements together using `.*`.

Comment: Have choosen this as answer because it seems to be the easiest solution which is applicable in my case.

Comment: Plus 1 for not resorting to `mat2cell`, `cell2mat` and its ilk.

Comment: Beware that if you get zeroes in your `T` you will not be able to differentiate which is a selected `0` vs derived `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one linear solution

```
mat2cell(T(nonzeros(bsxfun(@times,I,(1:numel(T)).'))),sum(I))
```

First logical index should be converted to numeric index for it we multiply `T` by each column of `I`

```
 idx = bsxfun(@times,I,(1:numel(T)).');
```

But that index contain zeros  we should extract those values that correspond to `1s` in matrix `I`:

```
 idx = nonzeros(idx);
```

Then we extract repeated elements of `T` :

```
T2 = T(idx);
```

so we need to split `T2` to `3` parts  size of each part is equal to sum of elements of corresponding column of `I` and `mat2cell` is very helpful

```
result = mat2cell(T2,sum(I));
```

result

```
ans =
{
  [1,1] =

      2
      4
      6
      8
     10

  [2,1] =

     3
     6
     9

  [3,1] =

     4
     8

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution using `cellfun` and `mat2cell`

```
nColumns = size(I,2); nRows = size(T,1); % Take the liberty of a line to write cleaner code
cellfun(@(i)T(i),mat2cell(I,nRows,ones(nColumns,1)),'uni',0)
```

What is going on:

```
@(i)T(i) % defines a function handle that takes a logical index and returns elements from T for those indexes

mat2cell(I,nRows,ones(nColumns,1)) % Split I such that every column is a cell

'uni',0 % Tell cellfun that the function returns non uniform output
```